# Mistake in code in recent blog post

Tags: bug, markdown, blog

[The recent blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/10/16/is-ai-enough-to-increase-your-productivity/?cb=1) looks like this:

> [image]

Timing of the blogpost aside, can the post be updated to remove `python` at the start of the code block? I presume someone intended to set the language and instead it rendered the language name.

Comment: Is it not plausible that the `python` text was actually part of the AI output (but leading and trailing backticks weren't)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed, thanks for spotting. You can also comment on the blog post itself for corrections like this.

Comment: Are you monitoring all comments made in any blog post?

Comment: Yes. We review every comment before it goes live.